# "Invalid Host header" warning when I route an AWS record to an IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, dns

Im currently trying to route an AWS route 53 record, the domain of which I purchased on AWS, to an elastic IP which is connected to an EC2 instance which is running a web app on port 80. When I type the elastic IP address into google, it works, but when I type in the record name(a.b.com) I get "Invalid Host header error". What's going on?